# Parsing Symfony Data Object

Tags: php, sql, symfony, oop, doctrine

Hey Guys I'm having trouble parsing data I get from a Doctrine Data Object.

This is my query:

```
    $dateNeeded = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-14 day"));
    $result = $this->em->getRepository('FYPCartBundle:PurchasedItems')->createQueryBuilder('pi')
        ->select('pi', 'o','cd','u','pv')
        //SELECT purchased_items.previewurl, CustomerDesign.designData, CustomerDesign.quantity, fos_user.email, fos_user.firstName, fos_user.lastName, orders.orderid, ProductVariant.displayName, purchased_items.ordernumber
        ->innerJoin('pi.orders', 'o')
        ->innerJoin('pi.customerDesign', 'cd')
        ->innerJoin('cd.user', 'u')
        ->innerJoin('pi.productVariantObj', 'pv')
        ->where('o.dateneeded = :dateneeded')
        ->setParameter( 'dateneeded', $dateNeeded )
        ->getQuery()
        ->setMaxResults(30) 
        ->execute();
```

Here is my loop to parse the data:

```
  foreach ($result as $order) {
       echo $order->email;
  }
```

The "echo $order->email;" statement returns nothing. I've checked the sql with phpmyadmin and it returns valid data.

How do I access that part of the data?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You are not selecting any email field... ->select('pi', 'o','cd','u','pv')

Comment: The email field comes from users (u)

Comment: $order->getUser()->getEmail();

Comment: Is getUser a function of users or purchased items?

Answer (score 0):

Order doesn't have email but has user. Also try not get fields directly, use getter methods (not `email` but `getEmail()`)

```
foreach ($result as $order) {
   echo $order->getUser()->getEmail();
}
```